# Jmeter-How to record AJAX calls

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a chat application and trying to record the same. When I post a message in chat app, the action is not getting recorded in Jmeter. I can see the pages in Jmeter but the posting message is not shown.
Basically, when I post a message in chat app, it is a Ajax call and a connection will be established. Whenever we post new messages, all the messages will go thru one connection and that connection never ends.
Please guide me how to record in this scenario.
Immediate response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out this post:
http://jmetertips.blogspot.com/2009/04/ajax-testing-with-jmeter.html